# MySQL - Can't Connect Locally

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am setting up MySQL on an Ubuntu 11.04 Server and had a problem connecting remotely. I changed the `bind-address` property in the `my.cnf` file to be the IP address of the server instead of `127.0.0.1` loopback. Now remote connections work fine, but I can't connect to it locally with my local web app. How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Answer at ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/139323/mysql-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address -- voting to close as offtopic so it can be closed as a duplicate over there ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can comment out or remove the bind-address from your `my.cnf` if you want mysql to listen on all IP addresses. Restart.